# Gradle won't install unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies

[image]

Gradle won't download and install the following dependencies even after I click "Install Repository and sync project" nothing happens.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Delete all your build folder form main project and then again rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

> File - Settings  - Sdk Tools - Update Android SDK Tools

Retry

Comment: It is not the case